# Error trying to run cron.php

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.1.0, cron

When I am trying to run cron.php I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'host' in
>   'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `cron_schedule`
>   AS `main_table` WHERE (status = 'running') AND (host =
>   'web02.myhost.ro')

The message is correct, there is no 'host' column in the 'cron_schedule' but why is it looking for it and where is this set up? Or what else can I do to get cron running.

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: a magento developer was able to take a look at our system and found the issue was within a 3rd party magento plugin that had a corrupt row in the database table that was causing the Mage__Helper_Data error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popular cronjob management extension [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) adds this column, either you installed it but it didn't get set up correctly or other code assumes that it has been installed.

Either way, I recommend to (re-)install the extension, it's a must have for every shop to monitor your cronjob activity and also improves cronjob reliability.

Comment: how do i reinstall I had just copied all the files through FTP.
Shall i overwrite those file with the ones you have linked in your answer?

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh Yes, then make sure the upgrade scripts are executed (i.e. clear config cache and refresh page OR use n98-magerun with the `sys:setup:run` command). If there's still not `host` column, you might have to delete the aoe_scheduler_setup row in the `core_resource` database table and try again.